# Read lines from a file into command window and expand variables

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, environment-variables

Im trying to see if its possible to read lines from a file into the command window and then write them back out to a file.  The tricky part is that anywhere in the file where there is text resembling a variable I would like it to be expanded.

The idea is to have a master batch file where I set the variables then read the default file in and replace the variables with values from the master.

File Contents

```
################################################################################
#
# Response file
#
################################################################################

################################################################################
#
# License Acceptance
#
# If you accept the license, <value> should be "true".
#
LICENSE_ACCEPTED=true

################################################################################
#
# Server host name
#
# The server host name. Server name should be FQDN
#
SERVER_HOSTNAME=%SERVER_HOSTNAME%

################################################################################
#
# Install user name
#
INSTALL_USER_NAME=%INSTALL_USER_NAME%

################################################################################
#
# Create user or not
#
# true:  create new user
# false: do not create new user. use existing user
#
CREATE_USER=false
```

My output for the INSTALL_USER_NAME line would be
INSTALL_USER_NAME=USER

The problem is that the variables don't seem to be expanded when they are read in and echo'd out to the file.

UPDATE:
Solution listed below

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "delims=" %%a in (E:\TEMP\WindowsAdditionalServer.properties) do (
call echo %%a>>"E:\TEMP\BASE.properties"
)
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add the contents of `E:\TEMP\WindowsAdditionalServer.properties`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`call` can be used as a kind of eval statement.

Try something like

```
SET INSTALL_USER_NAME=USER    
for /F "delims=" %%a in (E:\TEMP\WindowsAdditionalServer.properties) do (call echo %%a>>"E:\TEMP\BASE.properties")
```

(Untested)

Comment: Thanks!  Using the call inside the do section of the for loop allowed for the expansion of the variables in the incoming text.  (I also didn't have to double quote the incoming text.

Answer (score 2):

The order of expansion is roughly as follows:

1. Parameters, for example `%1`, or `%*`
2. Normal variable expansion, for example `%var%`
3. FOR variables, for example `%%V`
4. Delayed expansion, for example `!var!`
5. CALL with another round of normal expansion

You can use the CALL trick to expand variables after the FOR variable expansion, but that is relatively slow. Better to use delayed expansion.

You were on the right track when you enabled delayed expansion, but you also need to substitute `!` for `%` in your template file. So `INSTALL_USER_NAME=%INSTALL_USER_NAME%` should be changed to `INSTALL_USER_NAME=!INSTALL_USER_NAME!`. Then everything will work, and it will be faster.